# Change separator color in UISegmentController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

My project have `UISegmentController`. I have gray color separator. [image: Segment Controller]

in between the black line is the separator, there is white separator, but I want gray separator ? Please suggest some code.
My code is

```
- (void)changeColor{

   [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:83.0f/255.0f green:198.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:197.0f/255.0f green:197.0f/255.0f blue:197.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set it using an image. Note that you can have separate dividers between a selected and unselected segment or between two unselected segments.

[UISegmentedControl.setDividerImage(_:forLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:barMetrics:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618558-setdividerimage)

Intead of using a `UISegmentedControl` I find it simpler to use a set of `UIControl` elements.